# loading meteor template on click events

Tags: javascript, meteor

So, Basically i'm new to meteor(0.8.2) and trying to create a basic app having two templates(addnewPlace and Map) and a single button. What i need to get is that, when i click on "Add new Place" button, template "addNewPlace" should be loaded in body or else  template "Map" should be loaded. Help will be appreciated :)

My html code:

```
<body>
    {{> menu}}
    {{> body}}

</body>

<template name="body">
    {{#if isTrue}}
        {{> addnewPlace}}// tested this template individually, it works.
    {{else}}
        {{> maps}} // tested this template individually, it works too.
    {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="menu">
<h1>Bank Innovation Map</h1>
<input type="button"  value="Add new Place">
</template>
```

My js code:

```
Template.body.isTrue = true;
Template.menu.events({
    'click input': function(){
        //load a new template
    console.log("You pressed the addNewplace button");//this fn is called properly
        Template.body.isTrue = true;
    }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you obviously aren't changing anything in the click event (true before, true after). But also if you did, I think you might be better off using a session variable for this, to maintain reactivity.

```js
Session.setDefault('showAddNewPlace', false)
Template.body.isTrue = function() { Session.get('showAddNewPlace'); }
Template.menu.events({
    'click input': function(){
        //load a new template
        console.log("You pressed the addNewplace button");//this fn is called properly
           Session.set('showAddNewPlace', true)
    }
});
```

Comment: just to make sure, do i need to make any changes in html code? Coz I tried this solution and it does not work when i click on button.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I had a bug in the code. You need to make `isTrue` a function, in order to maintain reactivity. I fixed this now. Please try the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor 0.8.2 comes in with the dynamic template include feature. Just set a session variable value on click event and you would like to use the template name on the event.

```
Session.setDefault('myTemplate', 'DefaultTemplateName');
"click input": function (event) {
    Session.set("myTemplate", 'template_name');
}
```

You can now write this:

```
<body>
    {{> menu}}
    {{> body}}

</body>

<template name="body">
  {{> UI.dynamic template=myTemplate}}
</template>

<template name="menu">
<h1>Bank Innovation Map</h1>
<input type="button"  value="Add new Place">
</template>
```

You may like to take a look at this article for the reference:
https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/blaze-dynamic-template-includes/